# Hide / Show table rows based on time comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a table with dates in the middle column that have been parsed/formatted in Moment.js.

I also have two buttons, when clicked I want one button to only show table rows with dates < 24 hours away, the other button to show table row with dates that are dates > 24 hours away.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="button1">Less than 24 hours</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">More than 24 hours</button>

<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Table</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">12/24/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">11/23/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">12/24/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I think I have to use Jquery , this is what I was thinking.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var m = moment();
    var n = m.add(24, 'hours');
    var $dates = $('.dates');

$('#button1').click(function() {

    if ($dates.each > n) {
        $dates.hide();

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use moment [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) to check if the table date is *> 24 hours away* and [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) to check if the table date is between the current date and the next 24 hours (that is how I've interpreted *< 24 hours away*)

When parsing table date to moment object you have to [specify format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) because your input is not in ISO 8601 format.

Here a working example:

```js
$('#button1').click(function(){
  var $dates = $('.dates');
  var m = moment().add(24, 'h');
  $dates.each(function() {
    var date = moment($(this).text(), 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
    if (date.isBetween(moment(), m)) {
      $(this).parent().show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
  var $dates = $('.dates');
  var m = moment().add(24, 'h');
  $dates.each(function() {
    var date = moment($(this).text(), 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
    if (date.isAfter(m)) {
      $(this).parent().show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });
});

$('#button3').click(function(){
  $('tr').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="button1">Less than 24 hours</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">More than 24 hours</button>
<button type="button" id="button3">Show All</button>

<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Table</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">12/24/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">11/23/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">12/24/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you, this was similar to what I was trying to write

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested snippet).

```
$dates.each(function() {
  var date = moment($(this).text());
  if (date.isAfter(n)) {
    $(this).hide();
  } else {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

If `moment` has issues with parsing your datetime texts in your cells, you can specify the format explicitly, [see the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: Thank you , I did need to specify the moment format to get it to work properly .

Answer (score 0):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9379rLap/#&togetherjs=hiyfEfuas5). May it Helps!

JS:

```
$('#less24,#gt24').click(function() {
var target = $(this).attr('id');
var currentdate = new Date();
$('.dates').each(function(){

var diff=daydiff(currentdate,new Date($(this).text()));
if(target === 'less24')
{
if(diff <1 && diff >-1)
{
$(this).parent().show();
}
else
{
$(this).parent().hide();
}
}
else
{
if(diff <1 && diff >-1)
{
$(this).parent().hide();
}
else
{
$(this).parent().show();
}
}
});

});

function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/');
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}
```

HTML :

```
<button type="button" id="less24">Less than 24 hours</button>
<button type="button" id="gt24">More than 24 hours</button>

<table id="myTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Table</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">12/24/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">11/23/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="dates">12/24/2016 12:45 pm</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this does help